# Block User, Admin login - Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am trying to block User, Admin, Agent using Devise in Dashboard Controller - I am getting this error:

> undefined local variable or method `current_admin' for
>   DashboardController:Class

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  if current_admin.present?
    before_filter :blocked_admin?
  elsif current_agent.present?
    before_filter :blocked_agent?
  elsif current_user.present?
    before_filter :blocked_user?
  end

  def blocked_admin?
    if current_admin.present? && current_admin.blocked_admin?
      sign_out current_admin
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "This account has been Blocked - Please Contact Admin"
    end
  end

  def blocked_agent?
    if current_agent.present? && current_agent.blocked_agent?
      sign_out current_agent
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "This account has been Blocked - Please Contact Admin"
    end
  end

  def blocked_user?
    if current_user.present? && current_user.blocked_user?
      sign_out current_user
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "This account has been Blocked - Please Contact Admin"
    end
  end

end
```

I am new to rails, what's the Best way to optimize (DRY) code it. and to get ride of the error i mentioned above.

I also trying to do this, i have placed it in "application controller" in a different way.
The errors i get before removing this line :

```
redirect_to root_path, :notice => "This account has been Blocked - Please Contact Admin"
```

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return".

After removing this line

```
redirect_to root_path, :notice => "This account has been Blocked - Please Contact Admin"
```

> undefined method `model_name' for TrueClass:Class

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(Admin) && resource.blocked_admin?
      sign_out current_admin
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "This account has been Blocked - Please Contact Admin"
    elsif resource.is_a?(Agent) && resource.blocked_agent?
      sign_out current_agent
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "This account has been Blocked - Please Contact Admin"
    elsif resource.is_a?(Agent) && resource.blocked_agent?
      sign_out current_user
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "This account has been Blocked - Please Contact Admin"
    else
      #super
      "/dashboard"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to consider using external gem like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for authentication. There's really helpful documentation/screencast available for it. If you think it wont suit your needs you can always check for tools available [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization). Also you can try doing something like:

In your application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :check_for_blocking

def check_for_blocking
  if current_user.blocked?
    sign_out current_user
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "This account has been Blocked - Please Contact Admin"
  end
end
```

Main problem you will be facing is unifying of current_admin, current_agent into current_user. You need role management for that - which cancan or other similar role auth gem providing.

Comment: Thanks for writing, Yes, its true - to unifying of current_admin, current_agent into current_user is kinda prob and CANCAN is not good for this as well. I have a Question for that too ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610151/cancan-admin-agent-user

Comment: @Syed I think code-gijoe written exactly what I think about your cancan problem. You probably have bad architecture but you really need to refactor it until it get too complicated/hard to maintain.

Comment: I wish i could :) i have such a requirement that i have to do the way i am doing now - of course, as i am new to rails, there is no doubt that there are tones of nice ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

try adding these three lines

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
before_filter :authenticate_admin!
before_filter :authenticate_agent!
```